# Disable Outlook Reply to All in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

i have a Excel VBA Macro that sends an email to multiple people. i don't want to hide who it has been sent to, i just want to disable the Reply to All function on outlook.

I have tried the below, from outlook VBA, and it had no effect

```
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False 
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Forward").Enabled = False
```

Here it is in the code.

```
Set OutlMail = OutlApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With OutlMail
    .To = sendto
    .Subject = "Update for: " & Date
    Set rng = Workbooks("UpdateV2.xlsm").Sheets("EmailP").Range("A1:S75")
    Call SortAbs
    Workbooks("UpdateV2.xlsm").Sheets("EmailP").Calculate

    .ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False 
    .ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Forward").Enabled = False

    .htmlbody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial bgcolor='#FBEDD4'>" & _

    "Please note that this email is Confidential. Do not forward." & _
    "<BR><BR> <i> This is an Automatic Email - Generated by: " & GetUserFullName & "</i> <BR><BR></body>" & RangetoHTML(rng)

    .Display
 End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutlMail = Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you researched so far '[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)'. SO is not a code writing service but a Q&A place for problems/errors with code.

Comment: Sorry, added Code to Post

Comment: You need to remove the `.` from `.ActiveInspector` then it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed It.

Need to display the Email first.

then .ActiveInspector.CurrentItem needs to be on Application not the item

so i used:

```
Set OutlMail = OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

.Display
'.......
End With
outlapp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False 
outlapp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Forward").Enabled = False
```

Comment: No, there is no need to display the item first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to display the item first. Change the code to

```
OutlMail.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False 
OutlMail.Actions("Forward").Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .ActiveInspector to .GetInspector.

```
.GetInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False
.GetInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Forward").Enabled = False
```