# Disable "Reply to All" for TypeName of ActiveWindow - "Explorer"

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm attempting to disable the "Reply to All" action whenever there's a certain address (containing a lot of recipients) in the `To` field of the selected email (by utilizing an `Application.ItemLoad` event).

I'm able to do this just fine when the email is "popped out" ("Inspector" `TypeName` of `ActiveWindow`), but I haven't been able to disable it while the `TypeName` is "Explorer" (when the email hasn't been popped out, only selected).

Through my searches online I couldn't find the solution - most posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560831/disable-outlook-reply-to-all-in-excel-vba) are working with the email in Inspector.

I'm trying to find which object `.Actions` is a property of under `ActiveExplorer`, but perusing the object browser yielded no results...

I've tried `ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False`, which throws no error but the "Reply to All" button remains enabled. I've tried a variety of other combinations, but they all returned run-time error 438.

I'm sure the solution lies in disabling the action for the actual `Application`, but I cannot find `.Actions` anywhere!

Code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim curremail As Outlook.MailItem

    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)

        Case "Explorer"

            Set curremail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

            If InStr(curremail.To, "Address to not reply to") Then _
            'ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False <- This doesn't work (and no error)

        Case "Inspector"

            Set curremail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

            If InStr(curremail.To, "Address to not reply to") Then _
            curremail.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: How about `Application_ItemSend Event`?

Comment: I considered that, but I need them to be able to still email this address if truly intended - if they're entering it in the `To` field, they're intending. Most every time a message is sent in error, it's because they hit `Reply to All` by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the item afterwards:

```
curremail.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False
curremail.Save
```

Note that the "Reply All" button will remain enabled, but when you click it (or press Ctrl+Shift+R), Outlook will display "That action is not available for this item".

Comment: Aha! Fantastic. Funny how it doesn't grey out but displays that message. Thanks.