# How to check the TypeName of the Outlook ActiveWindow in python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am working on a python for outlook. It connects through a `win32com.client`. I am trying to check whether the `ActiveWindow` in Outlook is a Mail in its own Window(Inspector) or the Preview inside the Mainwindow (Explorer). In VBA this is checked like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298448/disable-reply-to-all-for-typename-of-activewindow-explorer):

```
Dim curremail As Outlook.MailItem
Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)

    Case "Explorer"
        Set curremail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    Case "Inspector"
        Set curremail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

End Select
```

Unfortunately, the I don't know how to get the `TypeName`. The python `type()` returns  `<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>` not the type of the `ActiveWindow`. Does anyone have an idea how to get the VBA `TypeName`, or if that is not possible how to determine whether the Mail is opened in the preview or its own window?

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

print(outlook.Inspectors.Count) #Can Determine the amount of open windows, but not if one is active
print(outlook.Inspectors.Item(1).Caption) #Caption of the first open window 

print(outlook.ActiveWindow())
print(type(outlook.ActiveWindow()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access `ActiveWindow` as `Inspector`, catch an exception (`try/except`), and access as `Explorer` if you end up in the exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the `ActiveWindow` object at runtime:

```
check = isinstance(outlook.ActiveWindow, Inspector)
```

Or simpler:

```
check = type(outlook.ActiveWindow) is Inspector
```

See [Determine the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/determine-the-type-of-an-object) for more information.

Comment: How do I get the `Inspector` to check against?

Comment: Inspector is a type (class) from the Outlook object model.